# Spring i18n question marks instead of text

Tags: java, spring, localization, internationalization

I hava i18n, but experience problems with russian letters. I have question marks `?????` instead of text. Configuration:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
    CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("ru"));
    resolver.setCookieName("locale");
    resolver.setCookieMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor changeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    changeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    return changeInterceptor;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/i18n/messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

Also I am using Thymeleaf.

```
<h1 th:text="#{message}"></h1>
```

Comment: Is it for russian letters from message source only? Can you see russian letters in pages?

Comment: @KenBekov yes, only for letters from message source. Yes, I can

Comment: It is possible you saved messages file in wrong encoding. Check file that contains russian messages saved in utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: in "addInterceptor" you are constructing the LocaleChangeInterceptor manually yourself. If this class depends on other spring beans (like MessageSource) then these are not injected. Find a way to let spring instantiate the LocaleChangeInterceptor (e.g. by using one of the various getBean() of the application context).

Answer (score 0):

Your files encoding is wrong. You should set it to `UTF-8`. If you use Intellij IDEA you can find it in the right bottom corner. If this option is disabled go to `Settings -> Editor -> File Encodings` and change the `Default encoding for properties files` parameter